# MutableList<DualCamera> Possible to construct without argument or mistake by google?

Tags: android, arrays, list, kotlin

```
data class DualCamera(val logicalId: String, val physicalId1: String, val physicalId2: String)

fun findDualCameras(manager: CameraManager, facing: Int? = null): List<DualCamera> {
  val dualCameras = MutableList<DualCamera>()

  // Iterate over all the available camera characteristics
  manager.cameraIdList.map ...
```

Google provides this code as an example. You can find it through the link below. Unfortunately my IDE tells me that a value parameter 'size' is missing from the constructor of `MutableList<DualCamera>`. Did Google made here a mistake or did i miss something? And how to fix it? I want to use this code.

https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/multi-camera

Comment: Their code doesn’t use `.size` of the MutableList. They used it on the `dualCameras` array.  And MutableList doesn’t have a constructor since it is an interface. Please copy and paste the exact error message and show the exact line of code it complains about.

Comment: e: {...}\MainActivity.kt: (161, 51): No value passed for parameter 'size'                       In my cutout this would be line 4.

Comment: e: {...}\MainActivity.kt: (161, 51): No value passed for parameter 'init'  -> this erreor i get as well

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Yes, Google made a mistake. Use `mutableListOf<DualCamera>()` instead of `MutableList<DualCamera>()` so you don’t have to specify a size. I guess the error message calls it a constructor since it looks like one, but it isn’t technically a constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much Tenfour04. (-: The problem is solved and the code works properly now!